# How to show data as date wise in Angular5 or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to show the data as date wise in my angular 5 application. 
I have uniq dates list array and data array. I want data like below

```
19/01/2018
```

Hyderabad,
Chennai

```
20/01/2018
```

Chennai,
Delhi

```
21/01/2018
```

Hyderabad,
Mumbai

> Arrays I have like this

```
dates_list = [19/01/2018, 20/01/2018, 21/01/2018];
data_list = [{
name: "Hyderabad"
date: "19/01/2018",
}, 
{
name: "Chennai"
date: "19/01/2018",
}, 
{
name: "Chennai"
date: "20/01/2018",
},
{
name: "Delhi"
date: "20/01/2018",
},
{
name: "Mumbai"
date: "21/01/2018",
},
{
name: "Hyderabad"
date: "19/01/2018",
}
]
```

Please suggest me how to do this. Thanks

Comment: one thing you can do is convert date into timestamp then you can compare them easily, but there may be some better approach

Comment: You want to make a groupby, see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwy6jf)

TS:

```
filterdArray: Array<any> = [];

  dates_list = ['19/01/2018', '20/01/2018', '21/01/2018'];
  data_list = [{
    name: "Hyderabad",
    date: "19/01/2018",
  },
  {
    name: "Chennai",
    date: "19/01/2018",
  },
  {
    name: "Chennai",
    date: "20/01/2018",
  },
  {
    name: "Delhi",
    date: "20/01/2018",
  },
  {
    name: "Mumbai",
    date: "21/01/2018",
  },
  {
    name: "Hyderabad",
    date: "19/01/2018",
  }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.getValiDates();
  }


  getValiDates() {
    this.dates_list.forEach(el => {
      this.filterdArray.push({ key: el, data: this.data_list.filter(data => data.date == el) });
    })
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of filterdArray; let i = index">
    {{d.key}}
    <div *ngFor="let data of d.data">
        {{data | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please vote up if it helped so others can find it easily.